# Install older version of pytorch with GPU support using conda

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda, conda

I would like to install `pytorch` `1.11` using `conda` with `gpu support` for a specific cuda version, e.g. `11.6`.

One can do the following to install latest version:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.6 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

And [HERE](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/) says how to do it for older version of pytorch but no gpu support:

```
conda install pytorch==1.11.0 torchvision==0.12.0 torchaudio==0.11.0 -c pytorch
```

So, then does the following install a `pytorch 1.11` with `gpu support` using conda?

```
conda install pytorch==1.11.0 torchvision==0.12.0 pytorch-cuda=11.6 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pytorch-cuda` package is a new metapackage only introduced three weeks ago - it is not pertinent to any thing but the latest PyTorch builds. Instead, for older packages you directly specify the `cudatoolkit` version for the environment.

Please note that `pytorch=1.11` only supports CUDA versions 10.2 and 11.1-11.5. There are no builds that work with 11.6. See [Anaconda Cloud](https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch/files?version=1.11.0).

**Example: CUDA 11.5**

```bash
conda install pytorch=1.11.0 torchvision=0.12 torchaudio=0.11 cudatoolkit=11.5 -c pytorch -c conda-forge
```